# How do I redirect to FilterPending.aspx immediately without using any button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public partial class DummyLoginPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AdminMainMenu.aspx");
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Pending Order Status")
        {
            Response.Redirect("FilterPending.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Drop down list

Comment: put `AutoPostback="true"` in your drop down list, in markup.

Comment: Please don't use the comment section to provider further details. Consider updating your question if you have further information. Also a little explanation wouldn't hurt anybody. Show us what you have tried and where you got stuck. This will make it much more easier to quickly address your issue.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Do you need to redirect when the selection on the dropdown list is changed?